# Having trouble with css vertical menu under a <nav> tag

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSQDe.jpg

My Problem: In the vertical menu, the drop-down part pushes the below content further downwards rather than over-lapping above the below content. This web page uses css media queries.

```css
@charset "utf-8";   
 #wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:-15px;
  max-width:1020px;
  width:97%;
  background-color:#FFF;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:2px;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0px rgba(12,3,25,1.8);
  }
 #slider{
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  min-width:320px;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  }
 #slider img{
  width:inherit;
  }
 
 #header{
  min-height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:5;
  background-color:#fff;
  width:100%;
  display:inline;
  }
 #header img{  
  width:218px;
  height:139px;
  }
 
 nav{
  width:auto;
  }     
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right:#CF0;
 }
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:150px;
 height:100px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height:100px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #34D675;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #99D829;
 }
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 }
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
 }
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
 }
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 }
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 }
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
 }
 
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
 }
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
 display: none;
 }
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
 display: block;
 }
 
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
  }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
  }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
  }
 }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <title>NFF - Sri Lanka</title>
 </head>
  
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
         
              <nav>
<a href="#"> 
             <img src="file:///E|/NFF -Website/images/nfflogo.jpg" alt="NFF Sri Lanka Logo" width="218" height="139"  title="NFF Sri Lanka Logo" ></a>
                 
                        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show</br>Menu</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
                    
                 <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">INFO ￬</a>
                            <ul class="hidden">
                                <li><a href="#">National Rainforests</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Aninmals & Plants</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nature Convservation</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ￬</a>
                          <ul class="hidden">
                                <li><a href="#">Our Mission & Vision</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Donate us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                      </ul>
   </nav>
    </div>
        
      <div id="slider">
         
              <img src="images/slider.jpg" alt="NFF Sri Lanka slider" title="NFF Sri Lanka Slider">
            
      </div>                 
  </div>
    <p style="text-align:center; padding:0px;"> &copy; Copyright 2014 - Damitha N. Wanniarachchi </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.hidden` and `position: relative;` to `.hidden` for `@media` query `max-width : 760px` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dow87q6o/)**

```css
.hidden {
    position: absolute; /* Add this */
}
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:-15px;
    max-width:1020px;
    width:97%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:2px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0px rgba(12, 3, 25, 1.8);
}
#slider {
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
    min-width:320px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
#slider img {
    width:inherit;
}
#header {
    min-height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:5;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    display:inline;
}
#header img {
    width:218px;
    height:139px;
}
nav {
    width:auto;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
 li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right:#CF0;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
 li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:150px;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:100px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #34D675;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
 li:hover a {
    background: #99D829;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
 li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
 li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
 li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
 li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
 li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
 ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
 .show-menu {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
 input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
 @media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    .hidden {
        position: relative; /* Add this */
    }
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <nav>
<a href="#"> 
             <img src="file:///E|/NFF -Website/images/nfflogo.jpg" alt="NFF Sri Lanka Logo" width="218" height="139"  title="NFF Sri Lanka Logo" ></a>

            <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show</br>Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">INFO ￬</a>

                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li><a href="#">National Rainforests</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Aninmals & Plants</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Nature Convservation</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT ￬</a>

                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li><a href="#">Our Mission & Vision</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donate us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/slider.jpg" alt="NFF Sri Lanka slider" title="NFF Sri Lanka Slider">
    </div>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center; padding:0px;">&copy; Copyright 2014 - Damitha N. Wanniarachchi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
div1 {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

or

```
div1 {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

alternatively, you could adjust the margins on the lower portion, using negative margins:

```
div2 {
   margin-top: -100px;
}
```